# Excel Display Zeros in Number Without Error

Tags: excel, vba, numbers, format

In excel VBA how do I display the following numbers as they appear without generating the 'Number stored as text' error in the cell?

```
1.0
1.1
1.2
.
.
1.99
1.100
1.101
1.102
.
.
1.20
1.21
1.22
.
.
etc...
```

Comment: Could the decimal separator on your system be a comma? Does `1,1` trip the same warning? Excel uses the "regional settings" to determine the characters to use to format numbers and dates. The character that separates function arguments is the "list separator" character - in a "en-US" configuration, that's a comma, but then the "decimal separator" is a dot. In other configurations the decimal separator might be a comma, and the list separator a semicolon. VBA code is very US-centric, but Excel uses system settings.

Comment: That said it would be helpful to [edit] you post to include a short example (see [mcve]) of the code you're using to write numbers to worksheet cells and get these "number stored as text" warnings. If your code is assigning numeric values to `Range.Value`, there shouldn't be any reason for this to happen.

Comment: Are they really numbers, or are they identifying tokens that you wrongly think are numbers?

Comment: X-Y problem. You are asking how to format the numbers, where the real question is how do you turn off a feature in Excel? This question is not really about programming.

Comment: Actually AJD you are correct. They are tokens, but excel thinks they are numbers and throws up the error. If I convert to text, I get the error. I want to stop the error.

Comment: See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of the number of decimal places that need to be displayed.  For example:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim s As String, i As Long, a
    s = "1.0,1.1,1.2,1.99,1.100,1.101,1.102,1.20,1.21,1.22"
    arr = Split(s, ",")

    i = 1
    For Each a In arr
        With Cells(i, 1)
            .Value = a
            brr = Split(a, ".")
            .NumberFormat = "0." & Application.Rept("0", Len(brr(1)))
        End With
        i = i + 1
    Next a
End Sub
```

[image]

This is based on the curious fact that if VBA puts a number-like string into a cell, Excel will convert it into a number:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim s As String
    s = "1.230"
    Range("A1").Value = s
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

On the other hand, if you want to enter text that look like numbers, but avoid raising the error flag, then:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText = False
End Sub
```